# Hover over div's nested items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In JQUERY I am trying to create a simple overlay, when you **hover** on `content1` it disappears and `content2` appears. Then you **mouseout** of `content2` and `content1` reappears.

This works fine except `content2` has `annoyingdiv` when the mouse moves over the `annoyingdiv` the **mouseout** event triggers. How can I work around this? Or how is this resolvable?

**HTML**

```
<div class="content1">blah blah</div>

<div class="content2">
    <div class="annoyingdiv">
        blah blah
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery javascript**

```
 $(function () {

    $('.content1').hover(function () {

        $(".content2").css("display", "block");
        $(this).css("display", "none");

    });

    $('.content2').mouseout(function () {

        $(".content1").css("display", "block");
        $(this).css("display", "none");
    });

});
```

Comment: Try experimenting with mouseleave instead of mouseout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`mouseleave` event](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead of the `mouseout` event.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS.

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/vaQTU/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="content1">blah blah content1</div>

    <div class="content2">
        <div class="annoyingdiv">
            blah blah annoyingdiv
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent .content2 {
    display: none;
}
.parent:hover .content1 {
    display: none;
}
.parent:hover .content2 {
    display: block;
}​​​
```

Comment: Valid point I could go this way but I have several components that are interlinked.